# How to sort a 2D array on the basis of a particular index in c/c?

Tags: c++, c

Suppose we have a 2D array A :

```
    A[3][3] = { {1 ,4 ,7},
                {6 ,2 ,3},
                {3 ,5 ,5}
              }
```

I want to sort it about index i (say 1)
the result should be

```
    A[3][3] = { {6 ,2 ,3},
                {1 ,4 ,7},
                {3 ,5 ,5}
              }
```

sorting about 0 will lead to

```
    A[3][3] = { {1 ,4 ,7},
                {3 ,5 ,5},
                {6 ,2 ,3}
              }
```

How to use the sort function to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

## **In C:**

*qsort* from *stdlib.h* sorts arrays of any length and any element size, to achieve what you want we need to feed it both these pieces of information, the length is the number of *rows* and the element size is the number of *columns*.

In addition to these it need to know how to compare the elements, *qsort* wants a function pointer with the signature int (*)(void *, void *). This function is called with pointers to each of the elements, which will be the address of the first number in each row, now we just have to compare the element of choice to each other. *qsort* expects a number less than zero in the case that **A < B**, zero for **A == B** and greater than zero for **A > B**, this is done by subtracting **B** from **A**. Since we got pointers we can just cast them to *int** and use index operators to compare the desired position against each others.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int sort_element = 1;// Choose a value from 0 to the column width

int intcmp( const void *a, const void *b ){
    const int *A = a;
    const int *B = b;
    return A[sort_element]-B[sort_element];
}
int main(){
    int a[3][3] = { 
        {1 ,4 ,7},
        {6 ,2 ,3},
        {3 ,5 ,5}
    };
    qsort( a, 3, sizeof(int)*3, intcmp);
}
```

As you see we need one compare function per element we are sorting with.

Answer (score 1):

## If you're using C++11:

Do a sorting on a column (`col`) like this:

```
int col = 1;
std::sort(A, A+3, [=](const int* a, const int* b)
{
    return a[col] < b[col];
});
```

## If you're using C++ (i.e. before C++11):

Define a functor type for the "less" operation like this:

```
class column_less
{
    int col;
public:
    column_less(int col) : col(col) { }
    bool operator()(const int* a, const int* b) const
    {
        return a[col] < b[col];
    }
}
```

Then do a sorting on a column (`col`) like this:

```
int col = 1;
std::sort(A, A+3, column_less(col));
```

---

[`std::sort` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Answer (score 0):

Try qsort, I believe it's in the stdlib.h Sort the pointers to the first element in each row.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your data type is `uint32_t`. You then want to treat this as sorting items that are `sizeof(uint32_t) * number_of_columns`. When you call your compare function, you will be passing it items that are this big. The compare function looks at the appropriate element inside whats its passed (really, a row) and then reorder the elements within the row.